# Additional search filter text box?

Tags: vb.net

Approximately 2 weeks ago, I asked a question on Stack Overflow, asking how to search a text file for matching strings entered into a search box, then another question on how to fix a case sensitive search issue.

That code has worked perfectly, but I now need to program a text box that allows the user to better define what results are put into the list box by entering additional keywords into an additional search text box, separate from the main search box. From the image below, you can see the first text box, which has 'Ablo' entered into it at the moment which is the normal search box, followed by the 'Additional Filter Text Search' text box. There is also a check box labelled 'Exclude Text', which will remove results that match the keywords in the 'Additional Filter Text Search' text box if the check box is checked, and if it is not, it will use the keywords in the 'Additional Filter Text Search' text box to get better results.

The first search text box allows the user to enter a keyword, such as a company name and if matching results are found in the text file, it populates the list box with said matching results. By including an additional search box, the user can better define the search results, by either searching for results that also matching the data in the text file or by excluding the results with matching strings from the list box.

[image]

The code to do a normal non-case sensitive search (code I asked for in previous question on Stack Overflow):

```
Dim path As String = "C:\ProgramData\WPSECHELPER\.data\Outlook Folder Wizard\outlookfolders.txt"
Dim search As String = tbx_FindText.Text
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(path).Where(
    Function(l) l.IndexOf(search, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
    ).ToList

lbx_OFL_Results.DataSource = Nothing
lbx_OFL_Results.DataSource = lines
```

My attempt to create the 'Additional Filter Text Search' text box code:

```
If tbx_AdditionalTextSearch.TextLength > 0 Then
    Dim path1 As String = "C:\ProgramData\WPSECHELPER\.data\Outlook Folder Wizard\outlookfolders.txt"
    Dim search1 As String = tbx_FindText.Text
    Dim lines1 = File.ReadLines(path1).Where(
    Function(l) l.IndexOf(search1, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
    ).ToList
    lbx_OFL_Results.DataSource = Nothing
    lbx_OFL_Results.DataSource = lines - lines1
ElseIf tbx_AdditionalTextSearch.TextLength = 0 Then
Else
End If
```

This code does not work, and my attempt of creating new variables with '1's on the end along with trying to take away the results from the '.DataSource' property didn't work.

If someone could help me fix this, with code that works with the checkbox to:

(A) Exclude the results from the list box that match the string in the 'Additional Filter Text Search' text box.

and

(B) To search for results that include keywords from both the main search box and the 'Additional Filter Text Search' text box.

...it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 3):

There are two extensions to the IEnumerable interface that could give you the expected results when working with a list of strings. These are [IEnumerable.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8) to remove members of a list from another list and [IEnumerable.Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8) to create an unique list from two lists.

```
If tbx_AdditionalTextSearch.TextLength > 0 Then
    Dim path1 As String = "C:\ProgramData\WPSECHELPER\.data\Outlook Folder Wizard\outlookfolders.txt"
    Dim search1 As String = tbx_AdditionalTextSearch.Text
    Dim lines1 = File.ReadLines(path1).Where(
    Function(l) l.IndexOf(search1, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
    ).ToList

    ' You call Except or Union depending on the state of your checkbox.
    if chkBoxExclude.Checked Then
       lines = lines.Except(lines1).ToList
    else
       lines = lines.Union(lines1).ToList
    End if
    lbx_OFL_Results.DataSource = Nothing
    lbx_OFL_Results.DataSource = lines
else ....
```

You need also to change the line that take the input value to search for. You should use the *tbx_AdditionalTextSearch* textbox for it, not the *tbx_FindText*

Comment: On the line 'lines1 = lines1.Union(lines1)' I get the following error: "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type '<UnionIterator>d__67`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.'  "

Comment: Add a ToList to both methods

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It now searches without throwing an error but it doesn't remove the other results, it effectively does nothing...

Comment: But you are taking the input from _tbx_FindText_ not from _tbx_AdditionalTextSearch_

Comment: I've just noticed that it is searching as if it was an 'OR' statement instead of an 'AND'. It needs to be so that whatever is in both the search box and the addition search text box both match the strings in the text file, not either - both. How can I fix this please?

Comment: I don't understand your request. Suppose the first list (lines) contains "A", "B", "C" and the second list (lines1) contains "A", "D" what should be the result when the checkbox is checked? And what should be the result when the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: The search needs to happen like this:

Data File: 

Line 1: ABC
Line 2: A
Line 3: B
Line 4: AB
Line 5: AD

Search parameters:

1st search box text: A
2nd search box text: B
Checkbox status: Unticked

Result: lines 1 and 4 as both contain "A" and "B".
Effectively, with the parameters this way, the search is an "AND" search.

__________________________________________________________

Search parameters:

1st search box text: A
2nd search box text: B
Checkbox status: Ticked

Result: lines 2 and 5, this is because these lines contain "A", but not "B".

Comment: Continuing from previous comment, I need to search the data file for lines containing text that is in the main search box.

Depending on whether I want to do an "AND" search, or a "NOT" search, I use the check box.

So, If I wish to do an "AND" search, I need to re-search the results from the first search and look for lines that also contain the text in the second search box.

However; if I wish to do a "NOT" search, I need to re-search the results from the first search and only take those lines that do not contain the text in the second search box.

Comment: So, searches are cumulative (one after another), which the search is currently not.